# how to add to cart using cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies, shopping-cart

/*am creating a shopping cart using PHP but whenever I add a new product it works(displays in cart page) but when I add the first product it adds again. am suppose to get just one product whenever I add the same product to cart multiple times*/

````
if(isset($_COOKIE['item']))
{
foreach ($_COOKIE['item'] as $name => $value)
{
$d=$d+1;
}
$d=$d+1;
}
else
{
$d=$d+1;
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['item']))
{
foreach ($_COOKIE['item'] as $name1 => $value)
{
$value=explode("__",$value);
$found=0;
if($cart_p_featured_photo==$value[0])
{ 
 $found=$found+1;
setcookie("item[$name1]", $cart_p_featured_photo."__".$cart_p_id."__".$cart_size_name."__".$cart_color_name."__".$cart_p_qty."__".$cart_p_current_price."__".$cart_p_name,time()+3600);

}

if($found==0)
{

  setcookie("item[$d]", $cart_p_featured_photo."__".$cart_p_id."__".$cart_size_name."__".$cart_color_name."__".$cart_p_qty."__".$cart_p_current_price."__".$cart_p_name,time()+3600);
}
}
}

else
{
    setcookie("item[$d]", $cart_p_featured_photo."__".$cart_p_id."__".$cart_size_name."__".$cart_color_name."__".$cart_p_qty."__".$cart_p_current_price."__".$cart_p_name,time()+3600);
}

}```
````

Comment: It's maybe better to store the cart in your database, give the user a 
random unique cart id and store that in a cookie. You then only have to check if the visitor has a cart cookie or not

Comment: @Baracuda078 thanx for ur suggestion